# Exclude the last fact row of a sum measure

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, msbi

I have a fact table that have 2 columns, '`timeInEventA`', '`timeInEventB`'. These columns store the difference in seconds between the actual ticket and the next ticket.

Ex: If I have a '`eventA`' at 2020/01/04 05:00:00, and the next ticket is 2020/01/04 05:01:10 the column 'timeInEventA' in the first ticket will have the value '`70`'.

There is the possibility of the ticket have neither eventA, neither eventB, so the two values in the fact table row will be 0.

This difference is calculated in the ETL and stored in the Fact Table.

**Problem: The client will filter the period by day. So he will choose 'between 2020/01/03 and 2020/01/05 give me the sum of timeInEventA and timeInEventB'. But was decided that the last ticket of the filter will be excluded because the next event is outside the filter range. So what I can do to exclude the last row register of the sum?**

My fact table have these 2 measure columns, a surrogate key to date dimension (ex: 20200103 ), a surrogate key for time with minute granularity( Ex: event occurred 05:03:22 will result in a 0503 surrogate key ), and a surrogate key to the customer dimension.

PS: In the past, I had this problem for another situation and was suggested me to have a sum measure pointing to the measure column, a lastvalue measure pointing to the same column, and a derived calculation subtracts the lastvalue( [MDX: Exclude a member that share same dimension property of a measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613293/mdx-exclude-a-member-that-share-same-dimension-property-of-a-measure/58615432?noredirect=1#comment103605080_58615432) ).

But for this situation, this approach don't resolve. If my filter is 20200102 to 20200108, this approach will exclude all 20200108 values in the calculation.

Best Regards,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

You need to define another measure with usage of last non empty value(This is done in the SSAS project, Cube structure tab->Define new measure). Then substract its value from your measure.

Comment: MoazRub, Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't work. If I put a filter in my MDX 'Give me the tickets from customer 'axz' between 2020/01/10 and 2020/01/15', this 'last non empty' measure will get the sum of the entire day 15. This is not what I want, I want only the last single element. If I have 14355 tickets in these days, I want only the ticket number 14355.

Comment: Can you share your fact table and sample data

Comment: MoazRub, my fact table have these columns: 2 measures, a surrogate key to the Customer dimension, a surrogate key to the Date dimension ( ex: 2020/02/14 ) and a surrogate key to the Time dimension ( values between 00:00:00 until 23:59:59 )

Comment: A customer can have 0, 3, 15, 75, 99, etc.. registers in the Fact Table daily, is totally aleatory, the tickets can be registered in any moment of a day, being able to share same hour, same minute. The last register of a day for a customer can be 11:32:14AM, 14:15:07PM, 21:17:12PM, 23:59:51PM, etc.. totally aleatory again